# Implied volatility surface modelling in filtered historical simulation

Tags: implied-volatility, garch, value-at-risk

What is the best way to model implied volatility surface in filtered historical simulation (other than keeping it constant)? Is it appropriate to apply GARCH-like model to every point on the surface? Any reduction techniques? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: A possible way: simulate paths with FHS until expiry date $T$, then return an array of underlying prices from such paths. You can fit a parametric density to this array, like a 2-Lognormal mixture, by means of the EM algorithm. Once you have the Lognormal mixture 5 parameters, you can get the option prices for that maturity using something like [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RND/index.html). From option prices, invert B&S and get the implied volatility, as usual. Repeat for different values of $T$ to get a surface.

Comment: @LisaAnn, how to map implied volatilities onto volatility smile ("moneyness") in this method? Will it be the same result if I simply integrate GARCH volatilities along each path up to maturity to get an estimation of the implied volatility? Thanks.